# Best way to open html data after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

The thing is that Im calling html data through an ajax call, but I want to display that data in the same page.
Im using document.open(), document.write(data), document.close() to display it and It works fine, but I have problem when I reload the page (mainly with ctrl + F5) because It doesn't load all the css and JS, I tried too with:

```
var w =  window.open("","_self");
            w.document.write(data);
            w.document.close();
```

But now when I reload the page, the url changes to wyciwyg//# followed by the normal URL (where # is any number) and it's loaded again without css and JS.
That's why I ask what is the best way to load html data to not get this kind of problem.
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here's part of my code:

- Table where I choose value that I want to check:

  ```
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th width="40%">Nombre</th>
          </tr>
    </thead>
  ```

  ${profesores.nombreProfesor}

  - JS function where I grab the value and send it to a function:

  $('#table tbody').on('click', 'tr', function() {
  var datos = new Object();
  llamar(datos);

  }

function where I call the servlet to retrieve the HTML data (In the servlet Im putting response.contentType as html):

function llamar(datos) {

```
$.ajax({
        url: '/servlet',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "",
        contentType: 'application/json',
        data: JSON.stringify(datos),
        success: function(data) {
          var w =  window.open("","_self");
            w.document.write(data);
            w.document.close();

        }
}
```

-Finally, the html Im retrieving in the servlet (It calls a jsp who has the table where im putting the data):

```
 <div class='panel-default'>
   <div class='panel-body'>
     <div class="table" style="font-size: 11px;">
          <jsp:include page="/tableToDisplayData"></jsp:include>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you please add all your code, HTML and JavaScript?

Comment: I suggest to take an invisible DIV, set the innerHTML of that div, and use DOM maipulation to replace the content of the part you want to change